# Org mode fontification error in #<buffer myfile.org> in python and ipython source blocks

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I am having problems with the fontification of `python` and `ipython` source blocks when the code contains curly brackets "{}". For instance, the following snippet

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :results drawer
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3])
plt.show()
a=1
print("a={}".format{a})
#+END_SRC
```

does not fontify correctly in either `python` or `ipython` source blocks.

As a consequence, when exporting the org file to HTML (C-c C-e h h), it fails with the following message:

```
font-lock-fontify-keywords-region: Invalid function: #<subr progn>
```

If changing the code snippet to:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :results drawer
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3])
plt.show()
a=1
print("a=%s" % a)
#+END_SRC
```

the block fontifies and the file is exported the HTML correctly.

Has somebody experienced similar problems?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I have the same problem; in my case the curly brackets are used to create a dictionary. This screws up syntax highlighting in addition to possible issues with export. A minimal example: #+begin_src python d = {} #+end_src This in GNU Emacs 28.0.50.

Comment: Hi @legion, I am using `scimax`. The problem was fixed in the following ticket: https://github.com/jkitchin/scimax/issues/389. It was related to f-string font-lock.